# How do leafcutter ants choose what plants to cut?

Tags: ant, instinct

I know that leafcutter ants don't actually eat plants and only use them to harvest fungi. How do they choose what plants to cut?

They won't touch anything in my garden, but if I plant roses, they'll completely wipe all the leaves and petals in a single day.

If some plants are better suited than others for their "farming", how do they know them?